# how do i alter an uploaded file in django before its saved to "uploaded_to"?

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

i have a form like this:

```
from django import forms
from manupulators import Replacer
class ContentForm(forms.Form):
    csvfile = forms.FileField( label='Select content file')
    txtfile = forms.FileField( label='Select changes file file')
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(DocumentForm, self).clean()
        csvfile = cleaned_data.get("csvdoc")
        textfile = cleaned_data.get("txtfile")

        if csvfile and  textfile:
            # Only do something if both fields are valid so far.
            """
            here goes nothing
            """
            worker = Replacer(csvfile,textfile)
            worker.open()
            worker.replace()
            worker.save() ##  how to do this i can alter the replacer to
                          ## return the changed stuff, how will it be saved to 
                          ## uploaded_to?

        return cleaned_data
```

the Replacer class  has internal methods called above that modify the uploaded text files, i'd like to save these files only after calling the replacer on them, im stuck on how to save  the manupulated  content file after modifying it in place of the original content.

here is the model:

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
    csvfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    txtfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out i could get the paths in the views,

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContentForm(request.blah,request.blah)
        if form.is_valid():
            docs = Document(csvdoc = ...,txtfile = ...,
                     app_user=...,)
            docs.save()
            pathone =  docs.csvdoc.path
            pathtwo =  docs.txtfile.path # all done
```